# Category, product and admin pages won't work without index.php in link

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, apache2

In order to enter in category, product or admin i need to specify index.php.

So linsk look like this site.dev/index.php/category_name.
I m using apache server.

Comment: Could you check if mod_rewrite is enabled on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about just calling the catalog/category model instead to get the URL from the category ID?

Example:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(7)->getUrl(); ?>
```

7 would be your category ID.